# Easiest way to sample from a multidimensional array with another multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 3d numpy array that looks like this

```
A = np.random.randin(0, 10, (23, 23, 39))        # H, W, D
```

And wish to random sample from its depth to reach a 2d array with **H** and **W** only

**Note** … this doesn't work

```
B = A[np.random.randint(0, 39, (23,23))]
```

Comment: Hey!

Would like just to clarify - what would you like the output to be? What size? Would you like a 23 x 23 matrix where each elemeent is randomly sampled from each depth array?

Comment: yes, the output will be a 2d array

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
B = np.array([x[np.random.randint(A.shape[2])] for y in A for x in y]).reshape(A.shape[:-1])
```

A little explanation: we use list comprehension to iterate, two dimensionally, over every sub-array in the list (y iterates over dimension 0, x iterates over dimension 1, we get arrays of dimension 2)

In each of these arrays, we then take a random number.

The result is a large one dimensional array containing one element from each sub-array. We finally resize the array so it is the shape of A, minus the last dimension (in our case, 23 x 23)|

Hope it's what you're looking for!

Comment: Good solution but i was looking for something simpler